SwiftUI NavigationTitle jumps down in detail view when using searchable list in NavigationView
I am working on a Swift project for iOS 17.0 or newer using SwiftUI in Xcode Version 15.4
I have three views:
View 1: Contains a NavigationView that navigates to View 2.
        NavigationView{
            NavigationLink(destination: TestView2()){
                Text("2")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
            }
            .navigationTitle("View 1")
        }

View 2: Contains a List with a .searchable modifier, which navigates to View 3 when an item is selected.
        VStack{
            List(){
                ForEach(items, id:\.self) { item in
                    NavigationLink(destination: TestDetailView(item: item)){
                        Text(item)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                    }
                }
            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText)
            .navigationTitle("View 2")
        }

View 3: A detail view displaying the selected list item.
        Text("Detail")
        .navigationTitle(item)

The problem occurs in View 3, where the navigationTitle unexpectedly jumps down when navigating from View 2. When the detail View is filled with infrmation the title is on top of the content. This issue only happens when View 2 has a .searchable modifier. If I navigate directly from a list without using .searchable or without an intermediary view, the issue does not occur.
Here is a gif of what's happening in slow motion:
Gif in which you can see the NavigationTitle jumping down
I have tried several solutions to resolve this issue:
Directly embedding the List in View 1 (with no intermediary view) avoids the issue, but I need to maintain the navigation structure.
Removing the .searchable modifier from the list in View 2 also prevents the problem, but the search functionality is important.
The occurs in the simulator and on a phisical device.

Try using NavigationStack instead of the old deprecated NavigationView.
Also do not use ForEach(items, id:\.self), make Item Identifiable and use
ForEach(items) instead,  and adjust your code, eg .navigationTitle(item.name)
